# OneLogin Signed Authnrequest HTTP-Redirect Method

Tags: saml-2.0, http-redirect, signed, onelogin

From what I have found OneLogin test connectors by default do not require a signed Authnrequest.  The Authnrequest made with HTTP-Redirect works fine without a signature. I am able to authenticate my user through OneLogin, and process the SAML response.

At this point I am trying to test code that signs the AuthNRequest.  Based on the specifications https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf the HTTP-Redirect method supports a signed AuthNRequest.  The url parameters would be "SAMLRequest=request&SigAlg=algorithm&Signature=signature".  I don't have a need for RelayState so it has been left out of the example.  The spec says the signature for the HTTP-Redirect method would be created using the query string parameters "SAMLRequest=request&SigAlg=algorithm", signed using the algorithm specified in the query string.  So the request itself is not signed.  I am signing using a self-signed certificate.  I have passed all the query string values to the OneLogin connector, and each time the AuthNRequest is processed by OneLogin successfully.  However, I have modified the signature value to not be valid, and even left it blank to hopefully have it fail and the AuthNRequest is processed by OneLogin.

FYI - I tried using https://www.samltool.com/sign_authn.php to create the signed AuthNRequest to make sure I was doing it correctly, but it only appears to provide the HTTP-Post, and not the HTTP-Redirect AuthNRequest.

I have the following questions:

1. Does OneLogin support a signed AuthNRequest through HTTP-Redirect?
2. Is there a way to setup a test connector to require a signed AuthNRequest?
3. How would I inform OneLogin about the public key from my certificate that was used to sign the AuthNRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Onelogin ( and other IDaaS ) don't support signed requests. I've never determined why that's the case but the direct answer is there's no support for that in Onelogin.